# Can i run multiple container laravel then connect on single container as webserver?

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, containers

I have many project with .php like laravel, wordpress or native php. Can i run that on multiple dokcer container and then connect it with single container as a database and webserver?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. its perfectly possible to run several sites on the same server using the same database service i have done it several times, the trick is have sommething that makes anyone unique, like the IP, the port, the domain or the home folder